# i want to declare payload of action but it's failed

Tags: javascript, redux

i had a trouble to add payload inside an action redux slice reducer,I had search in the internet but I don't find a solution to fix this problem so there's my code reducer:

```
topicsSlice code:
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const topicsSlice = createSlice({
    name : "topics",
    initialState: {
       topics:{}
    },
    reducers: {
        addTopic: (state, action={type: "topics/addTopic",payload: {id, name, icon}}) => {
      
       const newTopic = {id: id, name: name, icon: icon}
       state.topics = {...state.topics, id: newTopic};
        }
    }

});

export const selectedTopics = (state) => state.topics.topics;
export const {addTopic} = topicsSlice.actions;
export default topicsSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: What exactly do you want this to do? Usually you declare the payload when you call the action creator, not in the reducer definition. Or is this an attempt at destructuring the payload?

Comment: yeah,exactly i want destructuring the payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructuring works here like

```js
addTopic: (state, {payload: {id, name, icon}}) => {
```